# send notification on backend. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, process, notifications

I am inserting news on my portal and sending notifications to all registered devices when news gets inserted on database. I have so many registered devices so I want these notifications to be sent on backend so that user keep inserting news and for each inserted news notifications should be queued and sent on backend.

Currently I am inserting the news and after that sending notifications. Now the problem is that I can not insert another news until all the notification sending process completes.
My code is given below-

```
 public void InsertNews()
 {
   int newsId=insertNewsOnDb();
   string msg="My Json String";
   DataTable dt=getAllUsers();
   foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)// I want this process to run on backend  so 
   {                             // it does not affect the processing of
    string gcmId=dr["GcmId"];    //  inserting news. 
    sendPushNotification(gcmId,msg);
   }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How if, separate the programs of send notification and inserting news. But this means you need to declare a collection or list variable before call InsertNews(). So each time you call InsertNews, rather than call sendPushNotification, the collection of the notification of the news is added to the declared list. Then after the required news inserted, add the code to loop the declared list to send the notification.

or, use multithreading or asynchronous.

Comment: I want push notifications to be sent on a saparate process in which all the request will be queued and processed one by one.